# Is 其他人 any different from 别的人?

Tags: word-choice, difference

I guess the question could also be, is 其他 any different from 别的?

Is one any more formal, any more slang, any more rude, anything of the sort, than the other?

Or are they essentially the same?

Comment: I think they're essentially the same, and 其他 is a little bit more formal.

Comment: Although both mean other people, 别的人 can be used to point out a specific group or person, such as a special someone in a love affair. 其他人 can only mean other people in general.

Comment: 他人 also works, by the way. 他 means “other” in classical Chinese.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are similar in the meaning, however, not exactly the same.

其他 has a meaning of "the others", but it also has the meaning of "the rest", since this word is often used in the last when you are listing some categories, for example, "这个项目, 小王负责写代码, 小李负责 code review, 其他人去做测试." this word has the meaning in dividing the scopes.

别的 also has the meaning of "the others", for example, "我只知道这些, 别的我不知道了", in this sentence, the speaker tries to emphasize what he knows ("我只知道这些"), since "别的", from the literature meaning, "别"+"的", 别 has the meaning of different, so this word has the tendency in comparing and emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

其他人 is used more often than 别的人 in everyday life, although they have the same meaning.
Also in my opinion, 别人 sounds more appropriate than 别的人.

Answer (score 1):

其他 人 means "the rest of the people. 别的人 means "OTHER people." They are similar, but not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

No difference in meaning at all.

A good way to think of 其他人 may be "The rest of people" or "The rest of individuals". 别的人 should be translated as "other people", which is not grammatically wrong, but it does sounds unnecessary when you can just say 别人.

EX: Here is an example where it is acceptable to use either.
我已经开始着手解决这件事了, 其他人就不要再插手了.
我已经开始着手解决这件事了, 别人就不要再插手了.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases in China,其他人=别的人.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, “别的人” isn't used quite often,at least not used often by Beijingers, more common form is "别人"

“其他人” always represent the rest in a team, class, squad, etc. It's more formal, and more specific, and when you want to explicitly refer to some people, use this word, especially when you are assigning works to people. You can still use "别的人" or "别人" if you wish, but not if you're writing a news report, research paper, etc.

"别人" has the same meaning. But it's informal. When you're chatting with someone, use this word. Again, you're still allowed to use "其他人".

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there will be much difference.

> 其他人
>  qítāгéп
>  其他所指的就是另外的，额外的。
>  其他人所指的就是本身或涉及范围以外的人。

This definition is the same with 别的人, as far as my experience, I think you can exchange those two words in everyday life and in formal reports.

Answer (score 0):

It basically means the same thing, so you can use either one
它们几乎没什么区别，在各种场合中用哪种都可以。